# Broken Links in Help Center

Tags: bug, status-completed

On [this page](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there are two links that go to a dead proposal.  (Both of them say "this proposal", and one of them links to pedagogy, and the other to relationships).

These should probably be cleaned up.

Comment: Thanks for that. Sorted now.